# Does Gatsby miss good reference documentation?

Tags: gatsby

... or do I just not find/understand the proper docs? I'm new to Gatsby and many related technologies like React and GraphQL. Two examples referring to the [Gatsby Starter Blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/)

```
// layout.js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import { rhythm, scale } from "../utils/typography"

const Layout = ({ location, title, children }) => {
  const rootPath = `${__PATH_PREFIX__}/`
  let header
...
...
```

Is `__PATH_PREFIX__` a global variable or where does it come from? Where in the Gatsby docs do I find a List of all global variables?

```
// blog-post.js
...
const BlogPostTemplate = ({ data, pageContext, location }) => {
  const post = data.mdx
...
```

Where in the doc do I find a description of the page component and the component `props`? I do understand `data` and `pageContext` and I can imagine the meaning of `location`. But where do I find a complete description of the page component and all props-fields?

Comment: This question might be better suited to a github issue on the gatsby repo. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs it says.

> Use to prefix resources URLs. `pathPrefix` will be either empty string
> or path that starts with slash and doesn't end with slash.

Path prefixing is explained in details [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/)

Regarding globals, yeah, there is a lot of magic happening and documentation is not on the point in that area. But I feel that documentation is pretty good to get you started with the basics. I recommend that you get over [node APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages) to get the better understanding how you can control the build process.

Comment: Thanks @MarioNikolaus. This answers my question. Yes, Gatsby misses good reference docs.